# How to interpret lspci -tvv output

Tags: command-line, pci

Extract of `lspci -tvv` on a server with GPUs:

```
-+-[0000:b2]-+-00.0-[b3-b8]----00.0-[b4-b8]----08.0-[b5-b8]----00.0-[b6-b8]--+-05.0-[b7]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GP104GL
                                                                             \-0d.0-[b8]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GP104GL
```

What is the format relating to / how can I understand the output?

From what I've found online the tree output is usually:

```
[domain number:bus number]-+-device number.function number Device Description
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bus can be connected to other buses, and cascade; in your case, you have a root device (no longer visible in the diagram), to which a succession of bridges (with device numbers 00) connect successive buses (b2 to b8), to which the two GPUs are connected.

You can get more information on the devices by dropping the `-t`; you’ll then see the bridges, and be able to map the connections using the primary, secondary and subordinate bus identifiers.